# Using dynamic filters with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm developing an application (.Net Core 3.1, C# 8) that is using Entity Framework Core.

I would like to filter a table with several filtering options.

I'm getting the filter conditions in JSON and I'm deserializing it into an object. I want to write a where LINQ query which will filter the table based on those dynamic filtering options.

The twist is I need to manage the filtering with many options and combinations.

- You can filter for the `market`, `country`, `vendor` and the rest of the filter options will be `null`.
- You would like to filter for `country` and `vendor` then the `market` will be `null` and also the rest of the filter options.

I'm querying a huge table, so it is important to write a query which translates fully into SQL.

The following code is not working properly. I'm looking for something similar that can solve this issue:

```
var filters = new demoFilterEntity()
{
      Market = new List<string>() { "LAT", "NAM" }
};

var filteredData = demoMainRepository.GetAll().Where(x =>
      x.Market != null && (filters.Market != null ? filters.Market.Contains(x.Market) : false) &&
      x.Country != null && (filters.Country != null ? filters.Country.Contains(x.Market) : false)).ToList();
```

I would appreciate suggestions on how I can get through this and manage the filtering dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only `AND` conditions you can do it with just chaining `Where` clauses:

```
var query = demoMainRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Market != null); 
if(filters.Market != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => filters.Market.Contains(x.Market));
}
...
var filteredData = query.ToList();
```

Also as [@Lajos Arpad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436560/lajos-arpad) said maybe you need to consider combining fields null checks (i.e.  `x.Market != null`)  with the filters checks:

```
var query = demoMainRepository.GetAll(); 
if(filters.Market != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x =>  x.Market != null && filters.Market.Contains(x.Market));
}
...
var filteredData = query.ToList();
```

Comment: With [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) you can have `Or` operator as well.

Comment: @PeterCsala yes, or build it with expression trees yourself =)

Comment: What if we need the Or outside the where clause =>
if filter1.Exits {query.add Filter1} if filter2.Exists{ query.Add(filter2 as an OR filter)}; in other word apply Or to multiple Where statement

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently researching this topic and have found `dynamic lambda expressions` is a thing
The `.Where` method accepts `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>` type which you can create dynamically.

Kind of cumbersome but it works good once you wrap your head around it

I recommend this article in Codemag [Dynamic Lambda Expressions](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1607041/Simplest-Thing-Possible-Dynamic-Lambda-Expressions)