# Lambda Expression with If conditons

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a report and data querying using Lambda expressions.

I have six parameters as query parameters. Ex. Name,Age,eamil,DOB,position and department.

I want to query the table with empty or null parameters using Lambda expression.

I'm using .net core and Entity framework core.

Is there any way to fulfill this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dynamic filters with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832742/using-dynamic-filters-with-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var users = context.Users.Where(x => (Name == null || x.Name.Contains(Name)) && (Age == null || x.Age == Age)).ToList();
```

Do same for other parameters without quotes "(parameter == null || x.Column == parameter)".

If parameter is null, it skip. Otherwise, it use x.Column == parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing a query/filtering function which implements default parameters so in case some parameters are null they will not be part of the query.

example:

```
 public List<Student> GetStudents(string name = null, int? age){
 var students = context.Students;

 if (name != null) students = students.Where(p => p.Name == name );
 if (age != null) students = students.Where(p => p.Age == age);
  
 return students.ToList();
 }
```