# Does .Any() make the additional database call or not?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Consider the below line of code.

```
var query = ctx.Db.BannersV2.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(v => v.IsEnable == true);
query = query.Where(v => (!v.StartdateTime.HasValue || v.StartdateTime <= date.Date) && (!v.EnddateTime.HasValue || v.EnddateTime >= date.Date));
query = query.Where(v => v.BannerType == bannerType);

if (categoryId.HasValue && query.Where(v => v.CategoryId != null).Any())
{
   query = query.Where(v => v.CategoryId == categoryId.Value);
}
if (!location.IsNullOrBlank() && query.Any(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Location)))
{
    query = query.Where(v => v.Location.Contains(location));
}
if (!customerGroup.IsNullOrBlank() && query.Any(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.CustomerGroup)))
{
    query = query.Where(v => v.CustomerGroup.Contains(customerGroup));
}
var result = query?.ToList();
```

Here I am using AsQueryable() and then I am using .Where() Predicate as well as .Any() Predicate. Now I am worrying about or not sure about, does this .Any() predicate make additional calls to database or not?

Or when I use .ToList() or OrderBy() or Select() then only it will make additional database calls?

Comment: Yes, it needs to retrieve data. Ex: `query.Where(v => v.CategoryId != null).Any()` you are testing if in DB there is at least a record with `CategoryId != null`. To check this it must run a query.

Comment: Yes, `Any` makes database call.

Comment: This is really confusing, why I am saying? Because ChatGPT says no. Ref. Link https://chat.openai.com/share/dfea12c8-4ca2-4dda-99f8-c884a214b8e9

Comment: Terminating statements which do not return `IQueryable`: `Any`, `All` , `Count`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, `Sum`, `Min`, `Max`, `Average` always make database call in EF Core. Exception when they are used in projection (`Select`).

Comment: And this is why we do NOT trust ChatGPT for code

Comment: @MihirShah Not sure what is confusing here. I asked my magic 8-ball if it calls the DB and it said yes, so we're even on random chance giving an answer to this question...

Comment: Also, the easiest way to answer this question is to *run your code* and check the log output. It shows you every DB call it makes.

Comment: Just as a quesiton - why is the last line qeuery? - there is no chance query is ever null by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` is an operation causing query [materialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/intermediate-materialization), like `ToList`, `First`, `Count`, etc. So in your case with queryable build on top of ORM like EF Core it will result in database call (if `categoryId.HasValue` is `true`). The easiest option to check that would be enabling logging for EF and checking out the output. For example using the [simple logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
```

Based on the provided code it seems that `Any` calls are redundant though, just drop them (following the "standard" [dynamic filtering pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832869/2501279)):

```
if (categoryId.HasValue)
{
   query = query.Where(v => v.CategoryId == categoryId.Value);
}

// ...
```

Read more/notes:

- If `Any`/`ToList`/etc. is part of actual query, i.e. used in expression tree (like `query.Where(e => e.SomeCollection.Any())`) it should not result in additional query and should be translated into SQL
- [What is the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [EF Core: How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works)
- ASP.NET Core applications should have EF Core logging enabled [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3#aspnet-core-applications)

Comment: Not true. Any does not need to materialize - the ANy in this example can be done in the ONE trip to the database. It is not Any () at the end resulting in a boolean, it is Any () as a filter into a sub-expression. The one place that triggers a materialization is the ToList at the end.

Comment: @TomTom in this case `Any` is not part of expression tree.

Comment: Yeah, overlooked that. Damn. Yeah, that is reusing the query but materializing it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, `Any` needs to go to the database to actually determine the boolean value of the query that then can be used in the application code to branch.

As a useful rule of thumb, if it has an `Async` counterpart extension, then it queries the DB: [see `QueryableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). If you use `async/await` it'll also be more obvious where exactly the DB calls happen in the code.

As a second useful rule of thumb relating to your comment, don't expect a random sentence generator to give factual information about anything. Unlike EF, ChatGPT doesn't actually go anywhere to verify that its propositions are true, it just makes it up as it goes.

Comment: @TomTom How is it not? The question is "does `Any` here query the DB". The answer is yes. You can take umbridge with my snarky remark at the end, but the question is answered.